# Problem with Python Web App accessing Power BI embedded report

Tags: python, web, powerbi-embedded

I have trouble showing a power bi report in Power BI service suing a Python Web App. I got this error message:

Error Details:
400 Bad Request: Error while retrieving Embed token
Bad Request: {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Creating embed token for accessing dataset de376430-e631-4dbe-8722-2c9112f6e0ca requires effective identity to be provided"}}
RequestId: 052b6e05-8a39-408c-94d7-fe7091010d29

I have followed all steps in this article https://www.alphabold.com/power-bi-embedded-implementation-using-service-principal-and-python/

which is creating a Power BI embedded solution where I have created a Service principal service user, which I have put into a security group and this service principal is also an admin in the power bi workspace. I have tested this solution and a dummy report without dataset connection is showing up.

In the real test I have using a power bi report that has a dataset to a on prem sql server database through a data gateway. The report itself is working inside the power bi service, but when I try to make it show up in the web app, the error message comes up.

So I think it must have something to do with the data gateway and the connection to the on prem dataset. I have heard somewhere that I need to add the data gateway user to the sql database. Well, I hope somebody out there can help me with this

Regards Geir

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by many different factors, such as:

- Authentication Token is expired
- Dataset doesn't support effective identity
- Username wasn't provided
- Role wasn't provided
- DatasetId wasn't provided
- User doesn't have the correct permissions

Try these steps to see which one it is:

- Make sure the Authentication Token is refreshed
- Execute get dataset. Is the property IsEffectiveIdentityRequired true?
- Username is mandatory for any EffectiveIdentity.
- If IsEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired is true, Role is required.
- DatasetId is mandatory for any EffectiveIdentity.
- For Analysis Services, the master user must be gateway admin.

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-troubleshoot#what-is-the-difference-between-application-object-id-and-principal-object-id

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information, if you are using Django version >= 4.1, they have introduced [SecurityMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.security) that disables third-party cookies. Consequently, you may encounter issues with the Power BI embedded iframe. I struggled with this.

To allow third-party cookies, you may need to configure SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY in settings.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35461416)

Comment: Thanks Man. It helped me with the blank popup issue when i clicked in Login button in PowerBi Iframe.